# DreamFactory 2 authorization error

Tags: postgresql

I have installed DF2 from GitHub with a postgresql as a DB. There were no error messages during installation.
Then I entered into DF using admin's email/password. It was OK and I can see Profile of Admin user.
However I got following errors in apache2 log:

```
[Thu Nov 12 22:54:12.941506 2015] [:error] [pid 2886] [client 37.204.150.51:50852] REST Exception #401 > Invalid credentials supplied., referer: http://needgeo.com/dreamfactory/dist/index.html

[Thu Nov 12 22:54:13.904079 2015] [:error] [pid 2886] [client 37.204.150.51:50852] REST Exception #404 > Record not found, referer: http://needgeo.com/dreamfactory/dist/index.html
```

and in dreamfactory.log:

```
[2015-11-12 19:53:47] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:53:47] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:53:48] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.environment.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:53:48] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.environment.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:53:48] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:53:48] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.environment.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:53:48] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.environment.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:12] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:12] local.DEBUG: Resource event: user.session.post.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:12] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:12] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.admin.session.post.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:13] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.admin.session.post.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:13] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:13] local.DEBUG: Resource event: user.custom.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:13] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Service event: system.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.app.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Service event: system.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.service_type.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.config.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.service.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.environment.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.environment.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.role.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.admin.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.config.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:14] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.user.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.role.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.email_template.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.service.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.app.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.lookup.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.email_template.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.cors.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.app_group.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.ALERT: Could not get cors config from DB - SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1)  
[2015-11-12 19:54:15] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.event.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:16] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.event.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:16] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.script_type.get.pre_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:16] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.lookup.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:16] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.cors.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:16] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.app_group.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:16] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.script_type.get.post_process  
[2015-11-12 19:54:22] local.DEBUG: Resource event: system.service_type.get.post_process
```

If I press Refresh button it sends me on login page again. 
If I change something in the profile and press Update then nothing happened. Next visiting profile shows old data.

What might be the reason?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, my problem somewhere between a PostgreSQL db I use for my users and DF2 instance. 
I checked my PostgreSQL log and found:

```
2015-11-13 14:54:37 MSK STATEMENT:  select * from "cors_config" where enabled = 1
2015-11-13 14:54:38 MSK ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer at character 43
2015-11-13 14:54:38 MSK HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Of course it is not a solution but as soon as I migrated back to MySql db user storage it is began to work.